# Naviation Drawer calling an activity

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

How to call an activity from the navigation drawer.

thia ia my navigation drawer:

```
 @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_Home) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Home", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
        FragmentManager manager  = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.RelativeLayout, homeFragment, homeFragment.getTag()).commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_Profile) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Profile", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Share", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Send", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

I have an activity called ProfileActivity.java but i dont know how to call an activity through navigation drawer...help

Comment: What have you tried till now? Did you try starting the activity using an intent and calling startActivity method?

Answer (score 0):

Hello try this hope it may help you

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_Home) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Home", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
        FragmentManager manager  = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.RelativeLayout, homeFragment, homeFragment.getTag()).commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_Profile) {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Profile", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    startActivity(new Intent(YOUR_ACTIVITY,ProfileActivity.class));

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Share", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Send", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```